# Merge array with varying key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

So I have various arrays which do not always have the same key/value pairs in them. What I want to do is to be able to merge the arrays, but to add in empty key/value pairs if they don't already exist in that array, but do in others. It's hard to explain but this might explain it better:

```
$arrayOne = array('name' => 'rory', 'car' => 'opel');
$arrayTwo = array('name' => 'john', 'dog' => 'albert');
```

I need to somehow turn this into:

```
$finalArray = array(
    array('name' => 'rory', 'car' => 'opel', 'dog' => ''),
    array('name' => 'john', 'car' => '', 'dog' => 'albert')
);
```

I have been looking through PHP's documentation but can't find anything that will do this for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't even know an appropriate search term for what I want to achieve here, "array merge" isn't specific enough.

Comment: So first you want to know which keys each subArray should have in the result. For this you can get the keys(`array_keys()`) of each array and put them together into an array(`array_merge()` + `array_unique()`). Then you can put each array into the final array by using the array with all keys and fill in the values which you have(`array_replace()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Merge your separate arrays into one (into a temporary var) using `array_merge`
2. Get the unique keys of this new array using `array_keys`
3. For each separate array, loop through the new keys array and add an empty value for each key that is not in the array. Then push the separate array into a final array.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$arrayOne = array('name' => 'rory', 'car' => 'opel');
$arrayTwo = array('name' => 'john', 'dog' => 'albert');

$diff1=array_diff(array_flip($arrayOne), array_flip($arrayTwo));
$diff2=array_diff(array_flip($arrayTwo), array_flip($arrayOne));
//array_flip flips the key of array with value
//array_diff would return the values in the first array that are not present in any of the other arrays inside

foreach ($diff2 as $s) {
    $arrayOne[$s]="";
}
foreach ($diff1 as $s) {
    $arrayTwo[$s]="";
};
//set key that didn't exist in that array as ""

$finalArray[]=$arrayOne;
$finalArray[]=$arrayTwo;
//add the arrays to the final array

print_r($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arrayOne = array('name' => 'rory', 'car' => 'opel');
$arrayTwo = array('name' => 'john', 'dog' => 'albert');
$new = array_merge($arrayOne,$arrayTwo);
$new = array_keys($new);
$newarray = array();        
foreach($new as $value){            
$newarray[0][$value] = isset($arrayOne[$value]) ? $arrayOne[$value] :  '' ;
$newarray[1][$value] = isset($arrayTwo[$value]) ? $arrayTwo[$value] :  '' ;         
        }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($newarray);
```

**You can also use this short answer**

```
$arrayOne = array('name' => 'rory', 'car' => 'opel');
$arrayTwo = array('name' => 'john', 'dog' => 'albert');
$defaults = array('name' => '','car'  => '','dog' => '');
$arrayOne += $defaults;
$arrayTwo += $defaults;
$newarray = array($arrayOne,$arrayTwo);
echo "<pre>";print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on what Justin Powell outlined, I managed to come up with this code before the other two code examples were posted (thank you mamta & user6439245).

I also needed to take the keys containing numbers and sort them appropriately, otherwise my keys would've been indexed like `employer_1, education_1, employer_2, education_2`.

```
// get the initial form entries data
$entries = array(
    array('name' => 'john', 'car' => 'fiat', 'employer_1' => 'tangerine', 'education_1' => 'hideaways', 'education_2' => 'extras'),
    array('name' => 'rory', 'car' => 'opel', 'employer_1' => 'sagittarius', 'employer_2' => 'tangerine', 'employer_3' => 'thehideout', 'education_1' => 'knatchbull')
);


// create an empty array to populate with all field keys
$mergedKeys = array();

// push all field keys into the array
foreach($entries as $entry){
    foreach($entry as $key => $value){
        array_push($mergedKeys, $key);
    }
}

// remove duplicate keys from the array
$uniqueMergedKeys = array_unique($mergedKeys);

// create a new array to populate with the field keys we need to sort - the ones with numbers in
$keysToSort = array();

// push the number-containing keys into the array
$i=0;
foreach($uniqueMergedKeys as $uniqueKey){
    if(1 === preg_match('~[0-9]~', $uniqueKey)){
        array_push($keysToSort, $uniqueKey);
    }
    $i++;
}

// remove the number containing keys from the unique keys array
$uniqueMergedKeys = array_diff($uniqueMergedKeys, $keysToSort);

// sort the keys that need sorting
sort($keysToSort);

// put the newly sorted keys back onto the original keys array
foreach($keysToSort as $key){
    array_push($uniqueMergedKeys, $key);
}

$final = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($entries as $entry){

    foreach($uniqueMergedKeys as $key){
        //if($entries[$i][$key]){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $entries[$i])) {
            $final[$i][$key] = $entries[$i][$key];
        } else {
            $final[$i][$key] = '';
        }
    }

    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($final); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I think $entries[$i][$key][0]; is a typo, unless you want to store the first letter of the sub-array value only

Comment: Fair point, the real data is actually coming from WordPress and the values, i.e. 'john' were actually a single-row array like `array('john')` - edited, thanks :)